# reference request on observer

Tags: control-theory

May I ask from the  linear control theory community whether the solution of the following problem are available in the literature?

My system is $E \dot x=Ax+Bu, Y=Cx+Du$, $E,A$ are $m\times n$, $m\ne n$ matrices and there is no special assumption is made on the $\lambda E-A$ matrix pencil.

1. Detectability is necessary but not sufficient condition for the existence of Luenberger observer.
2. Causal Detectability is necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of Luenberger observer.

It will be great if I get some references/texts regarding these observer design line which shows the light on my asked questions.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Is $m > n$ or $m < n$, or do you only know that $m \neq n$?

Comment: And do you know anything about the rank of $E$?

Comment: For a Luenberger observer you also require an output usually of the form $y=C\,x+D\,u$. I assume this is the case?

Comment: Yes $E$ is singular and yes output equation is assumed.

Comment: complete your E and A matrices to squares and then look for impulse-free or the index of your system. Descriptor systems require more stringent conditions than mere luenberger observer design conditions

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an intuition based approach, you need to verify if this makes sense. You could multiply the equation with $E^T$ from the left to obtain

$$E^TE\dot{x}=E^TAx+E^TBu,$$

if you are lucky you will obtain an invertible matrix $E^TE$ such that you can multiply with the inverse of this matrix to obtain

$$\dot{x}=(E^TE)^{-1}E^TAx+(E^TE)^{-1}E^TBu.$$

Now, you would have obtained the standard form
$$\dot{x}=\hat{A}x+\hat{B}u,$$
in which
$$\hat{A}=(E^TE)^{-1}E^TA~\text{and}$$
$$\hat{B}=(E^TE)^{-1}E^TB.$$

If $E^TE$ is not invertible, then you could try the same with $A^T$ from the left to obtain
$$A^TE\dot{x}=A^TAx+A^TBu.$$

If $A^TE$ is invertible, then you can do the same as in the previous case.

Comment: Typically, $E$ is an $[n\times n]$ and rank deficient hence, $E^TE$ will be rank deficient either. I do not see any chance for $E^TE$ to be invertible. I'd suggest to look for some textbooks on singular/descriptor linear control systems. They may contain some related information.